# FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer, Version=5.0.0.0 on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-5, filenotfoundexception

I'm working on a microservices project based on .net 5 and recently add API versioning to the gateway endpoint (using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer`).
API Versioning is working on my local machine but after deploying my project on IIS, I ran into the following error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image: FileNotFoundException]

Let me know if you have the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer` on `Web.Medario.HttpAggregator.deps.json` file existing in publish output files.